# Program is Killed During Testing

Tags: c++, linux, memory, out-of-memory, kill

When I run my program I get the message `Killed` with some information about the script.  After doing some research on the problem, I found out that I wasn't deleting my dynamically allocated variables (stupid me!).  However, Now, I feel like I have taken care of that problem but I am still getting the `Killed` message in the terminal when I use Linux.

```
    //does the of the manipulation of the load factor.
    for (int tableSize = fileLength; tableSize < fileLength * 2; tableSize = tableSize + 500)
    {   

        //creates hash tables to be reused for each of the trials.
        for(int fileNum = 0; fileNum < NUMTIMES; fileNum++)
        {   

            Array_HashTable* linear_div_hash = new Array_HashTable(tableSize);
            LinkedList_HashTable *chain_div_hash = new LinkedList_HashTable(tableSize);

            Array_HashTable *doubleHash = new Array_HashTable(tableSize);        
            LinkedList_HashTable *mult_hash = new LinkedList_HashTable(tableSize);
            //Does the hashing for each of the files created.
            for (int index = 0; index < fileLength; index++)        
            {
                linear_div_hash -> Linear_ProbeDH(read[fileNum][index]);
                chain_div_hash ->  Division_Hash(read[fileNum][index]);
                doubleHash -> Double_Hash(read[fileNum][index]);
                mult_hash -> Mulitplication_Hash(read[fileNum][index]);
            }//ends the index for loop.

            optimalOutput("VariableSizeLinearCollisionData", fileLength, tableSize, linear_div_hash -> getCollisions(), fileAppendage);
            optimalOutput("VariableSizeDoubleCollisionData", fileLength, tableSize, doubleHash -> getCollisions(), fileAppendage);
            optimalOutput("VariableSizeDivisionChainingCollisionData", fileLength, tableSize, chain_div_hash -> getCollisions(), fileAppendage);
            optimalOutput("VariableSizeMultiplicationChainingCollisionData", fileLength, tableSize, mult_hash -> getCollisions(),fileAppendage);    

            linear_div_hash -> EndArray_HashTable(); 
            chain_div_hash-> EndLinkedList_HashTable();
            doubleHash -> EndArray_HashTable();
            mult_hash-> EndLinkedList_HashTable();

            delete  linear_div_hash; 
            delete  chain_div_hash ;
            delete  doubleHash ;
            delete  mult_hash ;
        }//ends the fileNum for loop
    }//ends the parent for loop with the size as the variable.
```

Basically the code works like this, the first for loop controls the size of the hash table. The second loop controls which file's data will be used to be hashed.  And a hash table object is instantiated for that.  The last loop calls the hash functions.  Then the stats are outputted to a file using the output function.  Then I use a similar function to a destructor to delete the dynamic variables from within my class. I can't use a destructor to do this because it was giving me errors for that.  Then I delete the objects.

What can I do?

Comment: I had no idea I was supposed to be doing that.  I had just went back and did it for all of them.  Thanks for the heads up on that.

Comment: No problem!  Glad you're making good use of S.O. and welcome!

Comment: @tpar: Given that you have included a code block that you want people to look at you should probably tag the question with the applicable language. It looks like c++, so I'll stick that in for you. Please change it if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @tpar44: Is there anything preventing you from declaring `linear_div_hash` and friends as just stack variables (non-pointers)? Since you're not using them outside the scope of the `for` loop, it would see easier to just let them be stack variables and let them going out of scope invoke the destructor for you.

Comment: @tpar44 Do you have any idea at what point in the code the program is killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the exhibited code you are calling `new` and then `delete` four times on objects of two types. That looks pretty good ***if*** the destructors of `Array_HashTable` and `LinkedList_HashTable` are correctly freeing any memory allocated by their objects.

If you are still leaking memory from this code, those objects would be my first suspect.

Comment: how would you correctly free memory in the destructor if there is only one pointer `int *array` that is an array? I just want to make sure that I did it right

Comment: @tpar: The programmer of the class (you?) has to keep track of any memory that the class allocates with `new` (or `new[]` since you talk about an array), and call `delete` (or `delete[]`) on that memory in the destructor.

Comment: okay so since that's what I do that's the only thing I can do to get memory? could it be that I am just running out of memory to use in the program?

Comment: @tpar: Can you estimate how much memory your program will allocate during a normal run? How does that compare to the available memory? If the expected allocation is as big or bigger than the available memory you could be running out. If it is much less than you are probably still leaking memory somewhere.

Comment: I found the leak in the code...i forgot to delete some dynamic vars

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on linux, you could use valgrind with this

```
valgrind myprogram
```

It will slowly but report many memory problems. If you still don't find it, you can heap profile it using massif

```
valgrind --tool=massif myprogram
ms_print <profile_output_file>
```

This will generate a graph of memory usage in time and the largest allocations of memory at several snapshot moments (including precise stack traces of where they were allocated).

Oh, build using `gcc -g` for debug info